# Clearing setTimeout issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

I'm trying to set "mouseactive" to true less than a second after a key command, but I would like to cancel that action if the key is pressed within that time period. However I can't seem to figure out how to do this. This is what I have...

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mouseactive = false;
        clearTimeout(t);
        var t = setTimeout("mouseActive()",800);
} else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mouseactive = false;
        clearTimeout(t);
        var t = setTimeout("mouseActive()",800);
}
});

function mouseActive() {
mouseactive = true;
}
```

But this doesn't work, it doesn't set mouseactive back to true... can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Cleaned up redundant code.

**More Edits:** Make sure your `var t` is defined outside any closure including `$(document).ready`. See below,

```
var t = null;

$(document).ready(function () {
   //..below code except for var t = null
});
```

Declare var t outside the handler.

```
var t = null;
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

   if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        mouseactive = false;
   } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        mouseactive = false;
   }

   if (t != null) clearTimeout(t);
   t = setTimeout(mouseActive, 800);
});

function mouseActive() {
   mouseactive = true;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't pass strings to `setTimeout`, you should pass functions.  It uses `eval` when a string is passed.  `t = setTimeout(mouseActive,800);`

Comment: @Rocket mm..  I just cleaned up his code.. that too included in cleanup.. Thanks though! I had it as string in my initial post before cleanup.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `t` is not in scope the 2nd time the function runs.  You need to make `t` a global variable .

```
var t;

$(window).keydown(function(e) {
if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mouseactive = false;
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(mouseActive,800);
} else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        e.preventDefault();
        mouseactive = false;
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(mouseActive,800);
}
});

function mouseActive() {
mouseactive = true;
}
```

P.S. Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`, pass functions.  It uses `eval` when you pass strings.

Comment: Nvm, that's because I didn't define it with the "var t" before. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

you are redeclaring "t" all the time, try this:

```
var t = null;  
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
            e.preventDefault();
            mouseactive = false;
            if(t != null)
            {
               clearTimeout(t);
            }
            t = setTimeout("mouseActive()",800);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            e.preventDefault();
            mouseactive = false;
            if(t != null)
            {
               clearTimeout(t);
            }
            t = setTimeout("mouseActive()",800);
    }
    });

    function mouseActive() {
    mouseactive = true;
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't pass strings to `setTimeout`, you should pass functions.  It uses `eval` when a string is passed.  `t = setTimeout(mouseActive,800);`